# Azure CosmosDB anonymous read access

Tags: azure, security, permissions, authorization, azure-cosmosdb

What is the simplest way to provide anonymous read access to a CosmosDB instance?

For example, in Firebase API I would only need to provide read access via the `rules` tab:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true, 
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cosmos DB does not have a way to disable authentication. It does offer separate keys for read/write and read-only, so you could provide a read-only access key for specific apps that don't need write access.

Alternatively, you can create your own anonymous-access API, which then reads directly from Cosmos DB (using either your standard read/write key or the read-only key).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakagon. Can you point me towards the instructions for creating an Anonymouse access API?

Comment: @MarkCooper - What I meant was, building your own API (and there are numerous ways to build APIs, whether REST or some other way), across many programming languages. You're in full control of how you build your API, and then your API makes calls to the database (which are authenticated). How you accomplish this is really up to you and your app's needs, your requirements, your language choice, etc - there's nothing I can point you to.